# how can I create incremental backups with xtrabackup automatically

Tags: mysql, backup, percona, innobackupex

It says on the [manual](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.3/xtrabackup_bin/incremental_backups.html) that if you want to create an incremental backup you can do it with the following command:

```
xtrabackup --backup --target-dir=/data/backups/inc1 \
--incremental-basedir=/data/backups/base --datadir=/var/lib/mysql/
```

where `/data/backups/inc1` is the incremental directory. So now if I want to create a cronjob (which I don't think I'm the only one), I have to figure out a way to name my directory every time I want to create a new incremental backup, which could be tedious.

Is there any way to maje xtrabackup to create directories using timestamps instead?

Comment: Use innobackupex instead of xtrabackup. The former is a wrapper and adds things like auto-timestamps to directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use built-in Linux command date to name directory as you want,
for example

```
xtrabackup --backup --target-dir=/data/backups/inc`date +%Y%m%d` (rest options)
```